# jasmine spyon with angular component

Tags: angularjs

I am having trouble creating jasmine spy. Angular 1.5 component with binding of current: &. I want to detect when the paging function in the notify function is called.

Test

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, _$componentController_) {
    model = {
        min: 1,
        max: 10,
        current: 1,
        notify: function () {
           return function paging(page){console.log(page);} 
        }
    };
    $componentController = _$componentController_;
}));

it('will not page forward on page 10', function () {
    model.current = 10;

    pager.pageForward();

    expect(model.current).toBe(10);
});
```

Component snippet

```
model.pageFoward() {
   model.notify()(model.current);
}
```

Comment: model.pageFoward is not a function. And I think you meant `forward` instead `foward`. It would be nice if you could rephrase your description, it's not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Enhanced the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you don't need to spy on, you should create a spy and return that in `model.notify`. Try:

```
var notifyReturnFunction;    

...
notifyReturnFunction = jasmine.createSpy('notifyReturnFunction');
model = {
    min: 1,
    max: 10,
    current: 1,
    notify: function() {
        return notifyReturnFunction;
    }
};
...
```

Now you can assert that it has been called:

```
it('will not page forward on page 10', function () {
    model.current = 10;

    pager.pageForward();

    expect(model.current).toBe(10);
    expect(notifyReturnFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // Or
    expect(notifyReturnFunction).toHaveBeenCalled(model.current);
});
```

Comment: Your solution looks promising but either I'm not implementing it correctly or there is something missing. I will try and debug. I can see the return notifyReturnFunction executing in the devtools, but the expect fails. I'll let you know what I come up with. Thanks for the help!!!!

Comment: I figured it out, I had some logic that was fouling it up. Your code worked!!! Thanks